# which client_id get consent on marketplace install?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

How can i choose which client ID gets consent during marketplace install flow?

When i click on 'test installation flow' in the api-manager, is see that a client ID is used in the consent flow:
[image: marketplace install test flow]

This client ID however, is not the correct one:
[image: list of client IDs]

I want to the marketplace install flow to use the first client ID: 'Web client 2', and not the 'apps Script' client ID

How can i configure the correct Client ID used for the installflow?

Comment: Look for the part in your code/program where you input your clientID and change that to the clientID you want to use. You may also want to read the 
[Set Up Your Project](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing#configure_additional_services)

Comment: Why it is important for you which client id are you using? Is it make any difference?

Comment: my appengine project, had two client_ids. The first i created for my javascript client, and the second was created from appscript when i connected it to my projected.  Next i configured the oauth flow, and it picked wrong one. you cannot use the appscript clientid for anything else but appscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally fixed this by following these steps:

- disconnect my appscript library
- remove the client-id i don't want in the installflow.
- wait a few minutes, and went to marketplace SDK
- do the testflow. as the clientid no longer exist it will pick a new one.
  (luckily it picked the right one the first try)
- reconnect the appscript again.

I think my users will have to reauthenticate once, but i'm not sure.